# Shell command passed to os.system() fails: sh: 2: Syntax error: "|" unexpected

Tags: python, bash, shell, bioinformatics

When I run my script in bash, I get the error: `sh: 2: Syntax error: "|" unexpected`. I don't know why, I want to use pipelines here, and a script in perl with that command works, but I need it in Python.

Example of input (text file):

```
Kribbella flavida
Saccharopolyspora erythraea
Nocardiopsis dassonvillei
Roseiflexus sp.
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys import os

input_ = open(sys.argv[1],'r') output_file = sys.argv[2]
#stopwords = open(sys.argv[3],'r')



names_board = []

for name in input_:
    names_board.append(name.rstrip())
    print(name) for row in names_board:    
    print(row)    
    os.system("esearch -db pubmed -query %s | efetch -format xml | xtract -pattern PubmedArticle -element AbstractText >> %s" % (name,
output_file))
```

Comment: What gets printed if you replace `os.system` with `print`? Does that look reasonable?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Have you read `man esearch`, `man efetch`, and `man xtract`?

Comment: This ubuntu, but this programs are eutilies from ncbi.

Comment: ok i see print...

Answer (score 2):

A possibly unrelated problem is that you aren't properly quoting the input and output file names in the command. Use

```
os.system('esearch -db pubmed -query "%s" | efetch -format xml | xtract -pattern PubmedArticle -element AbstractText >> "%s"' % (name, output_file))
```

However, even that is not foolproof for all legal file names (such as filenames that contain a double quote). I would recommend using the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system`, leaving the shell out of the process altogether

```
esearch = ["esearch", "-db", "pubmed", "-query", name]
efetch = ["efetch", "-format", "xml"]
xtract = ["xtract", "-pattern", "PubmedArticle", "-element", "AbstractText"]
with open(sys.argv[2], "a") as output_file:
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(esearch, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(efetch, stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    subprocess.call(xtract, stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=output_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `name` contains the newline that terminates the line read from input. When you interpolate `name` into the shell command, the newline gets inserted too, and the shell then treats it as the end of the first command. However, the second line then starts with a pipe symbol, which is a syntax error: pipe symbols must come between commands on the same line.

A good hint that that is the problem is found in the fact that `sh` reports an error at *line 2*, while the command seems to only consist of one line. After substitution, though, it is two lines, and the second one is problematic.